# MVC - Hide the control from the basecontroller.cs class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC project with following areas. And i wish to disable the "Create" button from the BaseController class.

1) View - CreateUser.cshtml

```
@model ViewModels.UserViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
}


    <div id="divButtons" style="text-align: right">
         <input type="button" id="btnCreate" value="Create" />
         <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
     </div>
```

2) Controller Class is AdminController.cs inherited from BaseController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
     return View("CreateUser", new UserViewModel());> 
 }
```

3) BaseController.cs

wish to control the visibility of the create button from the OnResultExecuted method present in this class. Since OnResultExecuted method will execute in the end of the lifecycle in the MVC page, so i thought it's a better place to hide or show the button control.

I am not able to get the handle to the create button from the OnResultExecuted method. Please suggest with the help of some code.

Comment: What do you mean _get the handle to the create button_? Are you confusing MVC and web forms? If you want to control the visibility of of the button, pass a bool value to the view e.g. `ViewBag.IsCreateButtonVisible = true;` and in the view, test the value and render it if true, other wise don't.

Comment: @Stephen - Yes, i confused it little with the web-forms. I am looking for a different approach. This way i would end up creating lots of viewbag objects for different controls in the view. I have taken the example for one input button, but i need to control other HTML elements also. Can i access the UserViewModel inside the OnResultExecuted method and set the properties ?

Comment: So do you mean your view model will have properties such as `bool IsCreateButtonVisible` that you want to set to control the visibility?

Comment: on what condition you want it to be disabled?

Comment: At the moment, i do not have properties in model to control the visibility. The condition should be - if the request to controller is for the CreateUser method, then only it should hide the button. Since the baseController.cs is the super class of various controller classes, i wish to control the element visibility w.r.t. this condition.

Comment: Your misunderstanding the process. When you call `return View()` the view engine generates the html based on the html in the appropriate view (including calling htmlhelper methods etc which return html). The controller has no knowledge of whats in the view. If you don't want to generate a particular html element then don't include it in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the only way to control the visibility is to set the property in the model, before calling the return view method in the action method.